blood angels armies extra models for black rage
i think somewhere in the past I heardthat if a player choses to run a blood angels army there was some game mechanic or rule that meant they had to make some rolls for each of thier marines to see if they succumb to the black rage and those that failed would have to be replaced with another model painted in the death company heraldry and conform to the rules for those models (I think the death company were more about the up close melee weapons so there was a chance you might lose a space marine equipped with some form of anti-armour weapon to a melee focused berserker, it also forced the player to essentially buy, paint, pack and carry 2 armies to every game
i have 2 question about this.

is my memory about this game mechanic for blood angels correct?
if so is it still an active rule or have newer editions done away with this?


This was a rule that existed in the 3rd edition Blood Angels codex:

For each of the squads listed below, roll a D6 at the start of the battle. On a 1, 2 or 3 the squad fights normally. On a 4 or 5, one model from the squad becomes a Death Company Space Marine... On a 6 one of the models in the unit joins the Death Company and you must roll again.

Affected squads were Honour Guard, Terminator Squads, Terminator Assault Squads, Veteran Squads, Veteran Assault Squads, Tactical Squads, Scout Squads, Assault Squads, Bike Squadrons, Scout Bike Squadrons, and Devastator Squads.
The Death Company cost 0 points as it was made up from models from your other squads. (In addition, if your army contained a Chaplain, he would always be accompanied by D3+3 Death Company in addition to any which randomly joined the Death Company).
This is no longer a rule in the 10th Edition of Warhammer 40,000. Death Company Marines, Death Company Marines with Jump Packs, and Death Company Marines with Bolt Rifles are regular datasheets which may (but do not have to) be chosen for your army, and models from other units do not randomly join them.
